# query to get Pivot in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table with data as shown below

```
    Task         Project    Amt Period
    -----------  --------   --- ------
    REVENUE 605  90020194   100 APR-20
    IE FTE       90020194   10  APR-20
    REVENUE 605  90020194   100 MAY-20
    REVENUE 605  90020194   100 JUN-20
    REVENUE 605  90020194   100 JUL-20
```

I need an SQL query to give the months in columns and respective amounts as shown below

```
    Task         Project    APR-20  MAY-20  JUN-20  JUL-20
    -----------  --------    ------  ------  ------  ------
    REVENUE 605  90020194   100     0       0       0
    IE FTE       90020194   10      0       0       0
    REVENUE 605  90020194   0       100     0       0
    REVENUE 605  90020194   0       0       100     0
    REVENUE 605  90020194   0       0       0       100
```

The periods are not fixed in number. I need a solution which can cope with a variable set of columns. Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: More generally, there are already a **stack** of [answered questions regarding `[oracle]+[pivot]` on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+pivot). Here is [a solution for fixed set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60670251/146325) and here is [a thread of dynamic solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491661/146325).

Comment: The periods are not fixed in number. I need a solution which can cope with a variable set of columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result using the following query and please be informed that `PIVOT` works with a defined number of columns so you must be knowing the period to use in the query beforehand.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TASK, PROJECT, AMOUNT, PERIOD FROM YOUR_TABLE)
PIVOT
(SUM(AMOUNT) FOR PERIOD IN ('APR-20','MAY-20','JUN-20','JUL-20'))
```

Comment: There really isn't much point in posting any answer until the Seeker has clarified their requirements, and especially for a topic which is already well-covered on this site.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I don't want to hard code the periods as these are not fixed all the time. Could you please tell me how can I achieve this without hard coded values.

Comment: You need to use the dynamic queries then!!